# Ada.Text_IO.End_Of_File buffering side effect

Tags: io, ada

I am trying to build an REPL in Ada after not having touched the language for many years.

If I check for END_OF_FILE in the code, the way that Text_IO buffers input and output changes.  I remember this being the case but cannot find a description of why or how to deal with this.  (I suspect this is a difference between terminal IO and file based IO)

Can anyone point me to a description of why Text_IO behaves this way?

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Exceptions; use Ada.Exceptions;
with Ada.Strings.Unbounded; use Ada.Strings.Unbounded;


procedure fred is
        Buffer: Unbounded_String := Null_Unbounded_String;
        L : integer := 0;
begin
        -- while (not End_Of_File)
        loop
                L := L+1;
                put("--> ");
                Buffer := To_Unbounded_String(Get_Line);
                Put_Line(Integer'image(L) & " " & to_String(Buffer));
        end loop;
exception
        when END_ERROR =>
                put_line("");
                put_line("Bye ...");
end fred;
```

Running this code as-is gives

```
--> a
 1 a
--> s
 2 s
--> d
 3 d
-->
Bye ...
```

If I uncomment the **while** statement I get

```
a
-->  1 a
s
-->  2 s
d
-->  3 d
```

Comment: OK I think I have the answer.  The End_Of_File function waits for input before testing if end of file.  In this case the prompt is not displayed before the user input.

I think I am stuck with the exception handler approach.

Comment: yes, there must be some input in order to determine if the end of file has been reached. As a side note, you can do input and output of `Unbounded_String` directly with `Ada.Text_IO.Unbounded_IO`

Comment: There is another problem with `End_Of_File`: if a file ends with a null line, `End_Of_File` returns True before the last line is read. For these reasons, I tend to always handle `End_Error` rather than use `End_Of_File`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `End_Of_File` requires user input, just place it right where you read the user input:

```vhdl
loop
   L := L + 1;
   Put ("--> ");
   exit when End_Of_File;
   Buffer := To_Unbounded_String (Get_Line);
   Put_Line (Integer'Image(L) & " " & To_String (Buffer));
end loop;
```